# Flask request with RuntimeError: Working outside of request context

Tags: python, flask, request, runtime-error

I execute the following python script in VScode

can extract mysql data and pass to .html to show as webpage's contant

```
# get_sql_where_02.py


import mysql.connector
import webbrowser
import time
import pymysql
from flask import Flask,render_template,request 

app = Flask(__name__)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="196.168.1.141",
  user="Main_root",
  password="password_123", 
  database="database_db",  
  auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
)
              
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
# mycursor.execute("SELECT P_TITLE,P_DESC  FROM webpage WHERE P_ID = 'en_1-01'")  
mycursor.execute("SELECT P_TITLE,P_DESC  FROM webpage WHERE P_ID = "+request.args["ProductID"])                     
                                         
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

print(myresult)    # does get the result I want 

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index_test_0203.html", myresult = myresult)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

- index_test_0203.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
      <p> this is {{myresult}}</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

- the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\custom_header_pra_1.12\test_showing_content_middle\get_sql_where_02.py", line 22, in <module>
    mycursor.execute("SELECT P_TITLE,P_DESC  FROM webpage WHERE P_ID = "+request.args["ProductID"])
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 316, in __get__ 
    obj = instance._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "C:\Users\chuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
    raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

I already read through the discussion and tutorial but don't know how to fix in my case

Answer (score 1):

you can't use request there, because the line `mycursor.execute("SELECT P_TITLE,P_DESC  FROM webpage WHERE P_ID = "+request.args["ProductID"])` is executed in the script startup. But you cannot access the request there.

You can access request after any request received.

use like this

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    # mycursor.execute("SELECT P_TITLE,P_DESC  FROM webpage WHERE P_ID = 'en_1-01'")  
    mycursor.execute("SELECT P_TITLE,P_DESC  FROM webpage WHERE P_ID =         "+request.args["ProductID"])                     

    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

    print(myresult)    # does get the result I want 

    return render_template("index_test_0203.html", myresult = myresult)
```

and remove these lines from the above place

Comment: "use like this" and  "remove these lines from the above place", sorry I don't get your idea, can you explain more? you mean the index_test_0203.html page was generate by executing get_sql_where_02.py, and I originally put 2 request in same .py, is that what you mean? I still can not guess ur solution meant